# Typescript: invert constraint on generic

Tags: typescript, generics, constraints

I've got objects containing functions:

```
const messages = {
  helloYou: (name: string) => `Hello ${name}`,
  goodbye: () => 'Good bye',
}
```

and a class managing this type of object:

```
class MyClass<T> {
  …
  getMessage<K extends keyof T>(name: K): T[K] {
    …
  }
  …
}
```

Then I can type safe call a function of the object registered in the class:

```
myObject = new MyClass<typeof messages>(messages)
myObject.getMessage('helloYou')('John')
myObject.getMessage('goodbye')()
```

The problem is that `getMessage` is returning a function, and in the case I don't need parameters (like in the `goodbye` example above), I will likely forget the empty parenthesis. So I tried to write a function, taking both the message name and the parameters. That's what I managed to do:

```
export function t<O extends Messages & { [P in K]: (arg1: P1) => string }, K extends keyof O, P1>(myObject: MyClass<O>, name: K, p1: P1): string
```

(this function is, of course, overloaded for 0, 2, 3, 4… function parameters)

This function is used this way:

```
t(myObject, 'helloYou', 'John')
```

This is working well and type safe, but I would prefer this method `t` to be a method of `MyClass` instead of giving `myObject` as first parameter of each call. It would indeed be more elegant to call it like that:

```
myObject.t('helloYou', 'John')
```

But, as you can see in method `t`, I managed to put constraints on the object type `O` (which correspond to the object type `T` registered in `MyClass`) depending on other function parameters. If I want `t` to be a class method, I need to invert constraints, i.e. constraint other parameters on `O`.

Does anyone know a way to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: why don't you just call the functions on the messages object like `myObject.messages.goodbye();`? Why do you pass generic `new MyClass<typeof messages>(messages)` if it could be simply omitted like `new MyClass(messages);`? What kind of a problem you are trying to solve? This really looks like some sort of overengineering.

Comment: I only printed enough code for you can understand the problem, that's why you cannot see the reasons for I want to do that. Just to clarify, actually, `MyClass` constructor does not take messages as parameters, but a map of messages. If I add that the real name of  ̀MyClass` is `I18n`, you will probably have a better idea of what I'm trying to do… ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish your goal using [`this` parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#specifying-the-type-of-this-for-functions).  If you name the first parameter of a function `this` and give it a type, you are constraining the `this` type in the body of that function to that type.  Just as it is an error to call a function with a parameter whose type does not match the parameter's type annotation, it is an error to call a method on an object whose type does not match the method's `this` parameter annotation.

In your case, take each function signature (overload and implementation) of the form

```
function t<
  O extends Messages & { [P in K]: (arg1: P1) => string }, 
  K extends keyof O, 
  P1> (myObject: MyClass<O>, name: K, p1: P1): string;
```

and convert it into a method by putting it inside the class definition and replacing the `myObject` parameter with a `this` parameter:

```
public t<
  O extends Messages & { [P in K]: (arg1: P1) => string }, 
  K extends keyof O, 
  P1> (this: MyClass<O>, name: K, p1: P1): string;
```

The new method should behave the same as your standalone function.  That is, `foo.t(bar, baz)` should be an error if and only if `t(foo, bar, baz)` is an error.  Try it out.  Hope that helps; good luck!